# How to boot custom .iso from CentOs 7

Tags: centos, centos7

I have a custom Windows 10 .iso mounted. I want to boot that .iso so I can overwrite my current VPS's OS (CentOs 7).

I can't get to the boot screen because when I'm connecting via terminal, ssh will only work once the server is completely on. I don't get access to a boot screen.

Most Google results for "centos install new os" take me to tutorials on how to install Centos, which is exactly what I don't want to do.

I found this: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/mount-custom-iso-on-kvm-vps/

The relevant part of the tutorial just skips over the relevant part:

> There you can see the system console and do the installation like how you usually would install an OS.

Comment: The typical method to reinstall a VPS is by selecting the image you want from the hosting providers  management system and redeployment. Many of the “better” providers offer support for uploading  your own images too. Please try that before proceeding with your current approach.

Comment: Additionally, by installing windows 10 you most probably violate the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a VPS, you must reboot the server and find the virtual terminal immediately. You only have a couple seconds to press any key to boot from the DVD drive, but it's possible. You just have to be quick from the boot to get into the terminal and start tapping keys. It's easy to miss.

Once that happens, you can go through and install Windows.

However, you need to build a custom ISO. More on that here: https://www.vultr.com/docs/windows-custom-iso-with-virtio-drivers/

A custom ISO will help you with the drive problems you'll find after trying to install the ISO direct from Microsoft.